# How to check string against multiple collections using streams

Tags: java, string, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying generate a specific String with the format: `*.*.*.*` it could be say `QUEUE1.NONE.QUEUE3.NONE`. To be specific this is a routing key for my rabbitmq to determine which queue to receive a specific event based on a collection of events, so `SET1` would contain events for `QUEUE1` etc etc.

The below is what I came up with but I think its too verbose, is there a more efficient way of doing this using streams?

Problem with using `flatmap` is that I have to return a different value if it is in different set, and `flatmap` just merges the sets.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(eventName).map(event->{
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()
          .append(Optional.of(event).filter(SET1::contains).map(t -> VALUE1).orElse(SKIP)).append(DELIMITER)
          .append(Optional.of(event).filter(SET2::contains).map(t -> VALUE2).orElse(SKIP)).append(DELIMITER)
          .append(Optional.of(event).filter(SET3::contains).map(t -> VALUE3).orElse(SKIP)).append(DELIMITER)
          .append(Optional.of(event).filter(SET4::contains).map(t -> VALUE4).orElse(SKIP));
      return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily complicating things with the optionals.  Why not just keep it simple?

```
String.join(DELIMITER,
    SET1.contains(event) ? VALUE1 : SKIP,
    SET2.contains(event) ? VALUE2 : SKIP,
    SET3.contains(event) ? VALUE3 : SKIP,
    SET4.contains(event) ? VALUE4 : SKIP
);
```